# Book about crazy telekinesis guy

Tags: story-identification, novel, telekinesis

There's this one book I've been searching everywhere for. It's about a boy who slowly starts to develop strange powers, initially telekinesis. He also starts to get angry a lot faster, and his girlfriend is the only one who can calm him. He reveals his powers when he finally gets so mad at a bully that he freezes the bully, then moves a flaming log in front of his face, while destroying the bully's car. Then he "blasts" away, a type of flight because of the telekinesis, and goes on the run. Over time he develops a type of pure energy shield which melts anything, stops bullets, and slows down time or something. Then, at the end of the book, he leaves his girlfriend to go totally on the run.
I remember all that, I just can't remember the book title, so I came here.

Anyone know the book?

Comment: Many of the things you mention match the protagonist in _The Stars My Destination_ by Alfred Bester. Telekinesis, quick to anger, the ability to speed himself up. The storyline doesn't add up though.